# jQuery / jqgrid / Editing form events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm working with the jqGrid and I want to know if exists an event to read a double click in the Editing Form?

For example, I have a grid with ColumnA and ColumnB. I want read the event when the user perform a double click under ColumnB (In the Editing Form).

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution of my problem

Here is the code, to this example I use the alert "TEST!!!"...

In the colModel

```
{ name: 'Total_uploads',
            index: 'Total_uploads',
            width: '100',
            editable: true,
            edittype: 'text',
            editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: '20',
                dataInit: function (el) {
                    $(el).click(function () {
                        alert("TEST!!!");
                    });
                }
            },
            editrules: { required: true },
            formoptions: { label: 'Total uploads: ', elmsuffix: '&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color : #0C66BE; font-family: Calibri">(*)</span>' }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean the double click in the `<input>` control of the edit form? Or you use another custom control? Do you use `datepicker`, `autocomplete` or other UI widgets or plugins attached to the `<input>` control?

Comment: @Oleg, thanks to reply. I basically want read the evenet double click in a single TextBox of all the Editing Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem ^^

Here is the code, to this example I use the alert "TEST!!!"...

In the colModel

```
{ name: 'Total_uploads',
        index: 'Total_uploads',
        width: '100',
        editable: true,
        edittype: 'text',
        editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: '20',
            dataInit: function (el) {
                $(el).click(function () {
                    alert("TEST!!!");
                });
            }
        },
        editrules: { required: true },
        formoptions: { label: 'Total uploads: ', elmsuffix: '&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="color : #0C66BE; font-family: Calibri">(*)</span>' }
    }
```